# PhalconPHP Joining Models Echo

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

Okay so I have two tables. One is called `Properties`, and the other called `PrInfo`.

Properties is the base table and PrInfo is another table which contains extra information.

I want to join them together so I can display information on the site.

```
    $query = Properties::query()
        ->leftJoin('PrInfo','pr.pr_id = Properties.id','pr')
        ->execute();
```

In my head every index queried should be joined with a row from the PrInfo table since declared "pr.pr_id = Properties.id"

However i can see in the executed query when I type just "print_r($query[1]);"
that indeed the pr_info table has been included, however I am not sure if it has  matched the row from the properties table.

I tried doing `print_r($query[1]['PrInfo']` however I just get an error.

Any ideas?

Has the following in the

```
          protected '_hasManyToManySingle' => null
      protected '_initialized' => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
      protected '_sources' => null
      protected '_schemas' => null
      protected '_behaviors' => null
      protected '_lastInitialized' => 
        object(PrInfo)[51]
          ...
      protected '_lastQuery' => null
      protected '_reusable' => null
      protected '_keepSnapshots' => null
      protected '_dynamicUpdate' => null
      protected '_namespaceAliases' => null
  protected '_modelsMetaData' => null
  protected '_errorMessages' => null
```

Comment: Why not just do a `var_dump($query);` and see what's inside?

Comment: It has the following at the bottom:

Comment: Check updated version ^^^

Comment: @Crembo i dont really know what it means by   object(PrInfo)[51]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually joining using `leftJoin()`, you should define a proper relation in the model as such:

```
class Properties extends Model
{
    ...

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany("id", "PrInfo", "pr_id");
    }

}
```

Read more about this at:
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#relationships-between-models

Comment: But this still wont allow me to fetch the data when i query

Comment: What do you mean? You can just do, for example, `$prop = Properties::findFirst(); $prop->prInfos` as long as prInfo is also a model

Comment: That adds another query